# How do I get .try() working in a Rails module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, module, try-catch

With Rails 2.3.5 I've written a module in RAILS_ROOT/lib/foo.rb which I'm including in some models via "include Foo" and all is well except where I try to use some_object.try(:some_method) in the module code - it throws a NoMethodError rather than returning nil like it would from a Rails model/controller/etc.  Do I need to require a Rails file from my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try` method is added by Rails' ActiveSupport module, so you need to `require active_support` within your module.

**Edit:** Alternatively, it's trivial to add it to `Object` yourself if you don't want to bring in the whole of ActiveSupport:

From [active_support/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/523002fe16366be69e830fd80bbd3d743d66fa16/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb):

```
class Object
  def try(method, *args, &block)
    send(method, *args, &block)
  end
  remove_method :try
  alias_method :try, :__send__
end

class NilClass #:nodoc:
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: tried that, same issue :-(

2) Error:
test_something(WithDescendantsTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `direct_descendants' for #<AdvertisementVersion:0x105cceb78>
lib/with_descendants.rb:40:in `try'